# .NET - using a custom type in a dataset

Tags: .net, dataset-designer

I have a .NET web app built using VS 2008. I included a strongly typed dataset that uses custom types in the table columns. I did this by manually editing the XSD file behind the dataset. This was all working fine until I did a big search and replace to change the name of the project. Now I can't get it working again no matter what I try. I keep getting "Error  101 Custom tool error: Failed to generate code. Column requires a valid DataType". I did have trouble with this when I built the app but I got through it somehow. This time I can't fix it no matter what I try. I've found a Microsoft knowledge base article that states this is impossible but I did it last time OK! Note that the custom type is part of a WCF service.

The KB is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968761/

Here's some of the XSD file:

msdata:DataType="EpGraphOnlineWebsite.EventsPerfect.BookingLightCollection, Service References.EventsPerfect.Reference.cs, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Day1Slot1"   msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Day1Slot1"   msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnDay1Slot1"   msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="Day1Slot1Column" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0"

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 2):

WTF! What sort of nut would be a developer :(

It just started working again by itself. I should know by now to restart VS and Windows when weird things happen. I guess it was just a glitch of some sort.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Cheers
Mark

Comment: I'll have to remember that the next time I do a name change with an XSD file in the project and start getting compile errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I know you are working in a source control system, it sounds like you need to revert the Project Name change, and temporarily remove the XSD file from the project until you can get the Project Name change implemented correctly.

Comment: Hi Robert

Thanks for the fast reply! I can easily go back to the old code and I have a copy which I am using to try and figure out what happened.
This is beside the point though. The only problem I have had with the name change was this dataset. The only compile errors I am getting are due to this.

Cheers
Mark